# Issue when transforming an existing site to multi-site with subfolders setup

Tags: multisite, network-admin

I am willing to migrate a new website to the customer server to replace its old one.
The old customer website used to be a single website (no network). I want to replace it with a network so as to be able to have one site in French, and another in English.

I would like it to use subfolders. So that :

> idakt.com --> contains French version of the site,
>
> idakt.com/en --> contains English version of the site.

I have followed the steps described [here](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/resources/the-complete-guide-to-creating-a-wordpress-multisite-installation) up to the update of the wp-config.php file with the following code :

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wordpress/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

Then I have put the following code in .htaccess file (according to the same guidelines)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I managed to create a new site `idakt.com/en` in my network, but it does not appear in the drop down menu of my dashboard, see screenshot. Therefore I am afraid something is wrong and I go ahead many problems in my next steps to update the 2 sites in my network...

NB: I do not care if all the links are broken with the set-up of the network.

I thank you very much in advance for your help!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can only use sub-directories with multisite on a fresh WP installation. Wordpress Multisite doesn't allow sub-directories for domains on an old site. So your possible solution would be to setup WP-Multisite using sub-domains as:

- en.idakt.com &
- fr.idakt.com

You may go through this article to learn more about WP Multisite: The [Ultimate Guide to WordPress Multisite](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/ultimate-guide-multisite/)

Answer (score 0):

Add yourself as a user of that website. It will appear.